# TensorFlow - dense vector to one-hot

Tags: python, tensorflow

Suppose I have the following tensor:

```
T = [[0.1, 0.3, 0.7],
     [0.2, 0.5, 0.3],
     [0.1, 0.1, 0.8]]
```

I want to transform this into a one-hot tensor, such that the indexes with the maximum value over dimension 0 get set to 1 and all the other ones get set to zero, like this:

```
T_onehot = [[0, 0, 1],
            [0, 1, 0],
            [0, 0, 1]]
```

I know there's `tf.argmax` to get the indices of the largest elements in the tensor, but is there any method which allows me to do what I want to do in one step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's a way to do this in one step, but there's a `one_hot` function in tensorflow:

```
import tensorflow as tf
T = tf.constant([[0.1, 0.3, 0.7], [0.2, 0.5, 0.3], [0.1, 0.1, 0.8]])
T_onehot = tf.one_hot(tf.argmax(T, 1), T.shape[1])
tf.InteractiveSession()
print(T_onehot.eval())

# [[ 0.  0.  1.]
#  [ 0.  1.  0.]
#  [ 0.  0.  1.]]
```