# How to replace tensorflow softmax with max for generating one hot vector at the output layer of Neural Network?

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, one-hot-encoding, softmax

For a classification problem, softmax function is used in the last layer of the Neural Network.
I want to replace the softmax layer with the max layer that generates one hot vector with one set to the index where maximum value occurred and set all other entries to zero.

I can do it with tf.argmax as suggested in [TensorFlow - dense vector to one-hot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44724948/tensorflow-dense-vector-to-one-hot) and [Tensorflow: Convert output tensor to one-hot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46841116/tensorflow-convert-output-tensor-to-one-hot), but these are not a differentiable way of doing it and gradients cannot be calculated.

If not exact 0's and 1's can be obtained then values should be close enough.

I was thinking to apply softmax multiple times but it is not recommended and I do not understand the reason behind it.

Please suggest a differentiable solution.

Comment: Why do you want to _replace_ the softmax layer? You can have it and use it for training, then add an argmax on top of it and use it only for prediction

Comment: Because loss will be much higher if the wrong prediction is done at the output layer. It can improve training time.

Comment: You don't improve training time by pretending your model does not make mistakes

Comment: The model will make mistakes, but the loss will be much higher for each.

Comment: What matters is not the value of the loss, but its gradient

Comment: Usually, at a high loss, gradient norm is also high, that is why the initial steps are large, and as loss decreases, we reach a local minimum and gradient becomes zero.

Comment: Entirely agree with @BlackBear - we need the gradient and, as I've explained below, that's just not possible if the function isn't differentiable. The gradient tells us which 'direction' to move in order to reduce the loss. If we can't calculate that direction we can't learn

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood correctly, I don't think what you are describing is possible. In order for an operation to be differentiable we need to be able to find a gradient.

Intuitively, this doesn't make sense if you are just clipping all values to 0 or 1

UPDATE IN RESPONSE TO COMMENTS:

You *could* always use such an operation it in a **metric** calculation. This would give you your 'more accurate view' of performance during training (but would not be used to train - just reporting results back to you).

It's just not possible to use it for the loss/objective function as that's not how neural network learning works. I'll try to explain a little.

There are proper mathematical justifications and definitions that explain why the loss function needs to be differentiable but, intuitively, we can imagine that our optimiser needs a "smooth", "continuous" surface to work on.

Imagine walking blindfolded over a smooth, continuous plane and being tasked with finding the lowest point. One strategy is to tap your foot in a circle around you until you find the step you could take that gets you farthest down. Now take that step and repeat it all over again. Keep repeating until you are at the bottom with no downward steps left. One could think of Gradient descent optimisation in this way. We take small steps in the direction that gets us lowest each time getting closer and closer to the bottom.

Now, instead of a smooth plane, imagine a surface that is exactly flat except for a single cliff edge. No matter where you stand on that plane you cannot possibly know which direction to step in. If you are away from the cliff edge everything is exactly flat. Even if you are on the cliff edge you still don't know which direction exactly (you probably have 180 degrees to choose from) to get to the lowest point.

Does that make sense? Without a smooth continuous surface we cannot use the strategy of taking small steps downwards?

Comment: If not exact 0 or 1 is possible then something close enough is desired.

Comment: The idea is that your last layer (and last layer alone) is a softmax layer where each value represents the predicted probability that the sample belongs to a given category. Use that output to train against your 1-hot encoded labels.

Comment: in short - softmax is probably that 'something close enough' that you are looking for :-)

Comment: @abhi - You haven't mentioned WHY you are seeking to replace the softmax layer?

Comment: because I think loss calculation will be much more exact in this way.

Comment: @abhi  I think I understand what you mean - I have updated my answer to try to explain why its impossible. I hope it makes sense and helps

Comment: So why the loss will not be smooth if the output layer is one hot vector and target is also one hot vector, and we measure cross entropy loss?

Comment: the cross entropy part is fine but the one_hot isnt. (and if we compose operations ALL have to be differentiable). If you think about the borderline case then we could make a very small change in input and see a massive change in output (from `0` to `1`).

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no differentiable solution, that is why we use the `softmax` activation, because it is a differentiable approximation to the max function.